# Pandas groupby operations between groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with 4 fields: Locatiom Year, Week and Sales. I would like to know the difference in Sales between two years preserving the granularity of the dataset. I mean, I would like to know for each Location, Year and Week, what is the difference to the same week of another Year.

The following will generate a Dataframe with a similar structure:

```
raw_data = {'Location': ['A']*30 + ['B']*30 + ['C']*30,
            'Year': 3*([2018]*10+[2019]*10+[2020]*10),
            'Week': 3*(3*list(range(1,11))),
            'Sales': random.randint(100, size=(90))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)


Location    Year    Week    Sales
A   2018    1   67
A   2018    2   93
A   2018    …   67
A   2019    1   49
A   2019    2   38
A   2019    …   40
B   2018    1   18
…   …   …   …
```

Could you please show me what would be the best approach?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please include the desired output (I recommend you reduce your input to say 10 rows, and don't make it random). And also, have you tried it yourself yet? It's helpful if you add your attempt to the question.

Comment: As I know `randint` don't have the `size` argument [https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint). This is the correct code `random.randint(100, size=(90))` ?

Comment: @CarloZanocco It is probably `np.random.randint`, OP should clarify nonetheless.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Ohh right i forgot about that

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `from numpy import random` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `groupby` and `shift`:

```
df["Next_Years_Sales"] = df.groupby(["Location", "Week"])["Sales"].shift(-1)
df["YoY_Sales_Difference"] = df["Next_Years_Sales"] - df["Sales"]
```

Spot checking it:

```
df[(df["Location"] == "A") & (df["Week"] == 1)]
Out[37]: 
   Location  Year  Week  Sales  Next_Years_Sales  YoY_Sales_Difference
0         A  2018     1     99              10.0                 -89.0
10        A  2019     1     10               3.0                  -7.0
20        A  2020     1      3               NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great. I have never used shift() method inside a groupby. Thank you so much!